# Removing old Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3 throwing error verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate in Ubuntu Part 3

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl

This post only contains the missing list of ca-certs from this post: Removing old Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3 throwing error verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate in Ubuntu Part 1 and Part 2

I needed to do this because Stackoverflow has a limit of 30000 character per post and I couldn´t do it just in one.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     79 Mar  1 07:20 Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     98 Mar  1 07:20 Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     94 Mar  1 07:20 Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     94 Mar  1 07:20 Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     62 Mar  1 07:20 Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     72 Mar  1 07:20 IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     51 Mar 25 05:14 ISRG_Root_X1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ISRG_Root_X1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar  1 07:20 Izenpe.com.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Izenpe.com.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     83 Mar  1 07:20 NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     78 Mar  1 07:20 Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     70 Mar  1 07:20 OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GA_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     70 Mar  1 07:20 OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/OpenTrust_Root_CA_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Mar  1 07:20 PSCProcert.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/PSCProcert.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/QuoVadis_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     55 Mar  1 07:20 Secure_Global_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Secure_Global_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 SecureSign_RootCA11.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/SecureSign_RootCA11.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     53 Mar  1 07:20 SecureTrust_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/SecureTrust_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     72 Mar  1 07:20 Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Security_Communication_EV_RootCA1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Security_Communication_RootCA2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Security_Communication_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.crt
        -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1094 Nov 21  2014 ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     71 Mar  1 07:20 Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     73 Mar  1 07:20 Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Starfield_Class_2_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     80 Mar  1 07:20 Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     89 Mar  1 07:20 Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 Swisscom_Root_CA_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Swisscom_Root_CA_1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Mar  1 07:20 Swisscom_Root_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Swisscom_Root_CA_2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     60 Mar  1 07:20 Swisscom_Root_EV_CA_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Swisscom_Root_EV_CA_2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     63 Mar  1 07:20 SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     54 Mar  1 07:20 SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     50 Mar  1 07:20 Taiwan_GRCA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Taiwan_GRCA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     66 Mar  1 07:20 thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/thawte_Primary_Root_CA_-_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     61 Mar  1 07:20 thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     67 Mar  1 07:20 T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     67 Mar  1 07:20 T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     84 Mar  1 07:20 TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    104 Mar  1 07:20 TÜBİTAK_UEKAE_Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_-_Sürüm_3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TÜBİTAK_UEKAE_Kök_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_-_Sürüm_3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     88 Mar  1 07:20 TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2007.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TURKTRUST_Certificate_Services_Provider_Root_2007.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     96 Mar  1 07:20 TÜRKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_H5.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TÜRKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı_H5.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TWCA_Global_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     72 Mar  1 07:20 TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     76 Mar  1 07:20 USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     76 Mar  1 07:20 USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     69 Mar  1 07:20 UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/UTN_USERFirst_Hardware_Root_CA.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     99 Mar  1 07:20 Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G3.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     99 Mar  1 07:20 VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G4.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     99 Mar  1 07:20 VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/VeriSign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G5.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     86 Mar  1 07:20 VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Mar  1 07:20 Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Visa_eCommerce_Root.crt
        lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     59 Mar  1 07:20 XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.crt
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not actually a question. It is simply spread a single question over multiple ones and this is the second part of it. Please note that each question at SO should be self-contained, so this is clearly not how SO was intended to be used. If your extensive information do not fit into a single question use services like pastebin for the details.

Comment: Steffen this is the only way to provide the complete list of ca certificates as stackoverflow is limiting the number of characters and I cannot provide it just in one post. This is just for debugging purposes.